# If an emergency vehicle approaches from ahead while I am driving on a two-lane road with no shoulder, what am I obligated to do?

Tags: california, traffic, driving

This morning, I was driving along a road that had one lane going each way. There was no shoulder; to my right was just a field. Up ahead, there was an emergency vehicle coming toward me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pull over to the right edge, stop, and wait until the emergency vehicle has passed. Do it safely.

[California Code Section 21806](http://www.leginfo.ca.gov/cgi-bin/displaycode?section=veh&group=21001-22000&file=21800-21809):

> [...] the driver of every other vehicle shall yield the right-of-way and shall immediately drive to the right-hand edge or curb of the highway, clear of any intersection, and thereupon shall stop and remain stopped until the authorized emergency vehicle has passed.

21807:

> The provisions of Section 21806 shall not operate to relieve
>   the driver of an authorized emergency vehicle from the duty to drive
>   with due regard for the safety of all persons and property.

Comment: In some states, you are supposed to pull over to the closest edge, not necessarily the right edge. On a divided highway in these states, people in the left lane should pull left.

Comment: Is it more important for a motorist to stop, or to slow down while avoiding any action which might impede the emergency vehicle by making it harder for following vehicles to get out of its way?  If there happens to be a line of cars behind a motorist reaching to the next intersection, stopping may result in that intersection being blocked.  Continuing slowly ahead would ensure that any following motorists would be able to leave a gap for the emergency vehicle.